# Open GL ES 2.0 - blank screen

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I trying to render my .obj file but get only blank screen. File reading code is tested, .obj file contains object with center at 0,0 coordinates. The question is only about GLES20 code. Could you help to figure it out what is wrong?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer
{
private Context context;
private Hashtable<String, ArrayList<Float>> obj;

public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    setRenderer(this);
}

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config)
{
    obj = new Hashtable<String, ArrayList<Float>>();

    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open("calculator.obj")));

        ArrayList<Float> vertex = new ArrayList<Float>();

        String name = null;
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.startsWith("v "))
            {
                String[] parts = line.substring(2).trim().split("\\s+");

                vertex.add(Float.valueOf(Float.valueOf(parts[0]).floatValue()));
                vertex.add(Float.valueOf(Float.valueOf(parts[1]).floatValue()));
                vertex.add(Float.valueOf(Float.valueOf(parts[2]).floatValue()));
            }

            if (line.startsWith("f "))
            {
                String[] parts = line.substring(2).trim().split("\\s+");

                obj.get(name).add(vertex.get(Integer.valueOf(parts[0]).intValue() - 1));
                obj.get(name).add(vertex.get(Integer.valueOf(parts[1]).intValue() - 1));
                obj.get(name).add(vertex.get(Integer.valueOf(parts[2]).intValue() - 1));
            }

            if (line.startsWith("g "))
            {
                name = line.substring(2).trim();

                obj.put(name, new ArrayList<Float>());
           }
        }

        reader.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    int i;

    ByteBuffer fByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(obj.get("calculator").size() * 4);
    fByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    FloatBuffer faces = fByteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    for (i = 0; i < obj.get("calculator").size(); i++)
      faces.put(obj.get("calculator").get(i).floatValue());            
    faces.position(0);

    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    GLES20.glClearDepthf(1.0f);

    int index[] = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, index, 0);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, index[0]);
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, faces.capacity(), faces, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, faces.capacity() / 3);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GLES20.glFlush();
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height)
{
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
{

}
}
```

Comment: There's nothing in your code that shows you are using a shader program.

Comment: Could you help with shaders? Is it possible to avoid shaders and use only GLES20 class?

Comment: No, you have to use shaders with GLES 2. Take a look here to get you started with shaders: http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started/

Comment: It is another learning curve learning shaders but well worth it in the long run. For just 2D rendering it is very easy to pick up.